# Extract image from URL using Jsoup

Tags: android, image, web, jsoup

I tried to extract an image from other websites with the following code and i had no problems, but them i tried with other website and nothing happend. no image came up.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(https://www.indiegogo.com/project/spy-cam-peek-i/embedded).get();
            // Using Elements to get the class data
            Elements img = document.select("div.i-project-card i-embedded img[src]");


            // Locate the src attribute
            String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
            //Download image from URL
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
            // Decode Bitmap
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

Comment: I need the only image on that link. this one: "https://images.indiegogo.com/projects/721478/pictures/new_baseball/20140322063421-EGGcolor_2.gif?1395495274"

Comment: If you actually looked at the source of that page you'll notice they don't use an <img> tag to display images. Instead, they use data-src on the div

Comment: yes but i didn't thought that would change anything. I do not have much time working with jsoup... can you tell me how it have to be the code to be able to extract data-src ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally y managed to grab the image.

The image src was inside a div under the attribute data-src like this

(<)div class="image" data-src="image.jpg><\div>

So I had to call the class of the div to then call its attribute data-src.  problem was that I didn't notice there wasn't a (<)img> tag which I was calling. So the final code was

Elements img document.select("div.image");

String imgSrc = img.attr("data-src");

Cheers everyone.